# Determine the conditions under which this game is fair

Tags: probability, combinatorics

QUESTION:
A drum contains balls numbered with natural numbers greater than $0$ that are used for a game. To play the game, the balls are shuffled and two balls are drawn at random. If the sum of the balls drawn is even, you win the game. If the sum of the balls drawn is odd, you lose the game. A game is fair if the probability of winning is equal to the probability of losing. Determine the conditions under which all the possibilities that the described game is fair.

MY SOLUTION:
Let $n=x+y \geq 2$ be the number of balls contained in the drum and let $x$ and $y$ be the number of balls numbered with odd and even natural numbers, respectively. The sum of the two balls drawn will be even if both are even or both are odd. The sum of the two balls drawn will be odd if neither of the above events occurs, that is, if one of the balls is even and the other odd.

To calculate the probability of winning $G$, that is, that the sum of the extra balls is even, we will find the number of favorable cases by the number of possible cases:

$\begin{array}{lll}
P(G) &=& \displaystyle \frac{C_2^x + C_2^y}{C_2^{x+y}}= \frac{\frac{x!}{(x-2)!2!} + \frac{y!}{(y-2)!2!}}{\frac{(x+y)!}{(x+y-2)!2!}} \\
&=& \displaystyle \frac{x(x-1)+y(y-1)}{(x+y)(x+y-1)} = \frac{x^2+y^2-x-y}{x^2+y^2+2xy-x-y}
\end{array}$

The probability of losing $L$, that is, that the sum of the extra balls is odd, is given by:

$\begin{array}{lll}
P(L) &=& \displaystyle \frac{C_2^{x+y}-C_2^x - C_2^y}{C_2^{x+y}}= \frac{\frac{(x+y)!}{(x+y-2)!2!} -\frac{x!}{(x-2)!2!} - \frac{y!}{(y-2)!2!}}{\frac{(x+y)!}{(x+y-2)!2!}} \\
&=& \displaystyle \frac{2xy}{(x+y)(x+y-1)} = \frac{2xy}{x^2+y^2+2xy-x-y}
\end{array}$

For the game to be fair $x,y \in N$, it holds:

$\begin{array}{ll}
& \displaystyle P(G) = P(L) \iff x^2+y^2-x-y=2xy \iff \\
& \displaystyle x^2+y^2-2xy=x+y \iff (x-y)^2=x+y
\end{array}$

The solutions are:

$\left( x= \displaystyle \frac{k^2+k}{2} \right) \wedge \left( y= \displaystyle \frac{k^2-k}{2} \right) \quad \forall k \in Z - \{-1, 0, 1 \}$

Comment: +1 : nice analysis.  A moderate shortcut is to ignore the denominator and simply assume that the number of ways of getting an even sum must equal the number of ways of getting an odd sum.  This implies $$\binom{x}{2} + \binom{y}{2} = xy.$$

Comment: Perhaps easier to write as #Evens=k(k+1)/2; #Odds = #Evens + (k+1), where k ∈ N.

Comment: What is the question?